How to create a 'MessagingExtensionResult' response with links?
I need to create a 'MessagingExtensionResult' response to "composeExtension/query" bot activity with text and links to login and sign up for users who are not logged in. When user clicks on a link a tab with Auth logic should open, where user can login/signup to an account.
I tried with 'Auth' and 'Config' type and suggestedActions. In the value field, I included a link to the tab like 'https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/${APPLICATION_ID}/${TAB_ID}', but clicking on the link doesn't open the tab.
Response example:
`{
    type: "auth", // or 'config'
    suggestedActions: {
        actions: [{
            type: "openUrl",
            value: `https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/${APPLICATION_ID}/${TAB_ID}`,
            title: 'some text',
        }]
    }
}`

Is it possible to open any tab from message extension? Or is it possible to display a custom text with links?
